# How to get windows boot loader back

Tags: windows

I uninstalled ubuntu 32 bit to get ubuntu 64 bit but when I did that when I turn on  my pc when I try to go to windows and get a black screen that just blinks and I do not have a windows disk

Comment: Get the answer at this site: [http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/)

Answer (score 0):

Grub will still work for you, all you need to do is give it a new place to store its files (since the original place was on the Ubuntu partition).  Windows machines frequently have several FAT partitions for recovery or tools, any of which will work to store the grub files.  Suppose you have a FAT partition on sda1,  just add a directory "boot" and install grub with that as the  boot-directory. Run the Ubuntu live media, mount the FAT partition in /mnt, so you see /mnt/boot  (make the boot directory now if you haven't already).  Then install grub there

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

This should pick up Windows and result in a bootable system.